# return what after a ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, servlets

I use `spring-mvc` and I have a ajax call which return `void` because i just update some data in the database. But in case of the user is not logged , i want to redirect him to a login page but i have to specify `String` as return not `void` so How can I handle this ?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add_to_fav") 
public @ResponseBody
void add_to_fav( ... ) {
    ....
    if(session.getAttribute("contact") == null)
        return "redirect:/login?next="+URLEncoder.encode(
                request.getRequestURL().toString() + "" + (request.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + request.getQueryString() : "")
                    ,"utf-8");

    ....

}
```

Comment: Return true/false ... if updated then true and if not logged in then false

Comment: but i want to redirect the user to login page

Comment: after the ajax on success check if false then redirect

Comment: No i wont add a extra round trip from client to server

Comment: You have no other option but to do this client side i.e. in Javascript. If you are using jQuery i can give you a clean solution you can configure globally in your app to catch all ajax requests with session timeout.

Comment: yes i'm using jQuery can u give me the global conf ?

Answer (score 0):

On this case you have some possibilities, like exposed below:
a
 - Change your return to a boolean and if false redirect the user to the login page.

- Change your return to a boolean and if false you call a modal to ask to the user the credentials
- Be sure previously that the user is logged or not, and if not, call the modal before the server call, so you will have less calls to server.
- If none of these options is fit to you, put more details about the application to help to think about.